# Star Schema. One to many cardinality

Tags: database-design, etl, data-warehouse, schema-design, star-schema

I am building the data warehouse based on the star schema and I've got difficulties with one issue as follows:

I have a dimension "Manufacturer" that can have several brands in his production line. And of course one brand belongs just to one manufacturer. **The dimension "Brand" cannot be created.**

How can I display it in my star scheme?

Usually in a star scheme the aggregation level is represented as an attribute according to just one unit/piece. But in our case one Manufacturer has several units. I thought that a bridge table will be a solution for that, but bridge table is more for many to many relationships (as one producer - many brands, one brand - many producers), but in our case it looks otherwise.

Please help to solve this issue. Thanks! :)

Comment: I mean that instead of dimension "Manufacturer" that can have several brands is not allowed to create the dimension "Brand" where theoretically is possible to put (one) manufacturer as an attribute and so fulfil the conditions. The goal is to create aggregation level within the dimension "Manufacturer" which will include several brands, like a "Group of brands" for example and **each brand inside of a group should have its own name and logo** as well. But how to show it in a star schema?

Comment: What's the reason for this requirement? Why can't you have both the Manufacturer and Brand dimensions?

Comment: Its a requirement of a training excercise.

Comment: Maybe the idea is to turn a star schema into a snowflake schema. Add a Brand dimension but joined to Manufacturer, not the fact table.